# editing .env files from front end django

Tags: django

I am using python decouple to store the secret keys in .env files as follows

```
STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = 'pk_test_51Hk2oFpiiCn94MIdRGFuRL0UeK003HdDUOGI'
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = 'sk_test_51Hk2oFL6Sy5bEid8yzJdxt5Eu700EKbjQTYu'
STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET = 'whsec_C0vOEGcAUCZYpf9'
```

and call in settings file as below

```
STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = config('STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY')
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = config('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY')
STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET = config('STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET')
```

now the question is how the strings in .env file can be replaced from front end, this is for future edit without the help of developers.

Comment: You shouldn't make it this complex! You could achieve this with a back-end API endpoint that perform such operations. But I think you should change it directly from the file-system instead!

Comment: it is bad practice to changes this kind of sensitive things from frontend section.

Answer (score 0):

make a model in Django and add keys through the admin side and use in setting file with try and except,

or

u can make a custom command if u can use the console.